# How to relate to type from outer context

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, ghc, type-declaration

Let us consider the following code snippet:

```
blah :: a -> b -> a
blah x y = ble x where
    ble :: b -> b
    ble x = x
```

This compiles fine under GHC, which essentially means that `b` from the 3rd line is something different than `b` from the first line.

My question is simple: is there a way to somehow relate in the type declaration of `ble` to a type used in an outer context, i.e. the type declaration of `blah`?

Obviously, this is just an example and not a real-world use-case for type declarations.

Comment: that solves a question i never dared to ask - how to make type annotation in where clauses - thx ;-) +1 of course

Comment: @epsilonhalbe: If you think about it, you've been making type declarations in where clauses all along: you start each program with `module Blarg where ...` :)

Comment: @TikhonJelvis whooo i didn't think about that either - maybe it's 'realizing-facts-about-where-clauses'-day ;-)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is possible with the [ScopedTypeVariables](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#scoped-type-variables) extension.  You need to use explicit forall's to bring the type variables into scope.

```
blah :: forall a b. a -> b -> a
blah x y = ble x where
    ble :: b -> b
    ble x = x
```

Trying to load this definition with ScopedTypeVariables enabled gives:

```
foo.hs:2:16:
    Couldn't match type `a' with `b'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for blah :: a -> b -> a at foo.hs:2:1
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for blah :: a -> b -> a at foo.hs:2:1
    In the first argument of `ble', namely `x'
    In the expression: ble x
    In an equation for `blah':
        blah x y
          = ble x
          where
              ble :: b -> b
              ble x = x
```

You can tell that GHC interprets the two `b`s as the same type because the error says that `a` and `b` are bound on the same line.

Answer (score 16):

If you don't want to use ScopedTypeVariables, you can use the good ole fashion `asTypeOf` function.

```
-- defined in Prelude
asTypeOf :: a -> a -> a
x `asTypeOf` y = x
```

---

```
blah :: a -> b -> a
blah x y = ble x where
    ble x = x `asTypeOf` y
```

Of course, this won't compile because of the type error.

### Update:

I would like to point out that sometimes you might have to be a little crafty to do what you want with `asTypeOf`. Take the following example that superflously uses `asTypeOf` because I don't want to think of a case that actually needs `asTypeOf`. Similar solutions would work the same for real world cases.

```
foo :: Bounded a => Maybe a -> a
foo m = x
  where
    x = maxBound -- Q: how do I make (x :: a) when given (Maybe a)?
    _ = Just x `asTypeof` m -- A: witchcraft!
```

Comment: That's nice, as I understand `asTypeOf` is something like `asTypeOf :: a -> a -> a` with an implementation `asTypeOf x y = x`.

Comment: That's the same thing as the definition I supplied (only that I wrote it in an infix manner).

Comment: I tend to call this providing a witness, but I'm not sure what the more proper name for the technique is. Just a way to pass in the dictionary, but don't know if there's a short name for it.